# In R, how do I wrap text around all words in a string, but a specific one(going from left to right)? Iteration and string manipulation

Tags: r, function, iteration, stringr, purrr

I know my question is a little vague, so I have an example of what I'm trying to do.

```
input <- c('I go to school')

#Output
'"I " * phantom("go to school")' 
'phantom("I ") * "go" * phantom("to school")'
'phantom("I go ") * "to" * phantom("school")'
'phantom("I go to ") * "school"'
```

I've written a function, but I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out how to make it applicable to strings with different numbers of words and I can't figure out how I can include iteration to reduce copied code. It does generate the output above though.

Right now my function only works on strings with 4 words. It also includes no iteration.

My main questions are: How can I include iteration into my function? How can I make it work for any number of words?

```
add_phantom <- function(stuff){
  strings <- c()
  stuff <- str_split(stuff, ' ')
  strings[1] <- str_c('"', stuff[[1]][[1]], ' "', ' * ', 
                 'phantom("', str_c(stuff[[1]][[2]], stuff[[1]][[3]], stuff[[1]][[4]], sep = ' '), '")')


  strings[2] <- str_c('phantom("', stuff[[1]][[1]], ' ")',
                      ' * "', stuff[[1]][[2]], '" * ', 
                      'phantom("', str_c(stuff[[1]][[3]], stuff[[1]][[4]], sep = ' '), '")')

  strings[3] <- str_c('phantom("', str_c(stuff[[1]][[1]], stuff[[1]][[2]], sep = ' '), ' ")',
                      ' * "', stuff[[1]][[3]], '" * ',
                      'phantom("', stuff[[1]][[4]], '")')

  strings[4] <- str_c('phantom("', str_c(stuff[[1]][[1]], stuff[[1]][[2]], stuff[[1]][[3]], sep = ' '), ' ")', 
                      ' * "', stuff[[1]][[4]], '"')
  return(strings)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is some butcher work but it gives the expected output :):

```
input <- c('I go to school')
library(purrr)
inp          <- c(list(NULL),strsplit(input," ")[[1]])
phantomize <- function(x,leftside = T){
 if(length(x)==1) return("")
 if(leftside)
   ph <- paste0('phantom("',paste(x[-1],collapse=" "),' ") * ') else
   ph <- paste0(' * phantom("',paste(x[-1],collapse=" "),'")')
 ph
}
map(1:(length(inp)-1),
    ~paste0(phantomize(inp[1:.x]),
            inp[[.x+1]],
            phantomize(inp[(.x+1):length(inp)],F)))

# [[1]]
# [1] "I * phantom(\"go to school\")"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "phantom(\"I \") * go * phantom(\"to school\")"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "phantom(\"I go \") * to * phantom(\"school\")"
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] "phantom(\"I go to \") * school"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a hack, but I think it gets at what you're trying to do:

```
library(corpus)
input <- 'I go to school'
types <- text_types(input, collapse = TRUE) # all word types
(loc <- text_locate(input, types)) # locate all word types, get context
##   text             before              instance              after              
## 1 1                                       I      go to school                   
## 2 1                                 I     go     to school                      
## 3 1                              I go     to     school                         
## 4 1                           I go to   school
```

The return value is a data frame, with columns of type `corpus_text`. This approach seems crazy, but it doesn't actually allocate new strings for the `before` and `after` contexts (both of which have type `corpus_text`)

Here's the output you wanted:

```
paste0("phantom(", loc$before, ") *", loc$instance, "* phantom(", loc$after, ")")
## [1] "phantom() *I* phantom( go to school)"
## [2] "phantom(I ) *go* phantom( to school)"
## [3] "phantom(I go ) *to* phantom( school)"
## [4] "phantom(I go to ) *school* phantom()"
```

If you want to really get crazy and ignore punctuation:

```
phantomize <- function(input, ...) {
    types <- text_types(input, collapse = TRUE, ...)
    loc <- text_locate(input, types, ...)
    paste0("phantom(", loc$before, ") *", loc$instance, "* phantom(",
           loc$after, ")")
}

phantomize("I! go to school (?)...don't you?", drop_punct = TRUE)
## [1] "phantom() *I* phantom(! go to school (?)...don't you?)"
## [2] "phantom(I! ) *go* phantom( to school (?)...don't you?)"
## [3] "phantom(I! go ) *to* phantom( school (?)...don't you?)"
## [4] "phantom(I! go to ) *school* phantom( (?)...don't you?)"
## [5] "phantom(I! go to school (?)...) *don't* phantom( you?)"
## [6] "phantom(I! go to school (?)...don't ) *you* phantom(?)"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like this

```
library(tidyverse)
library(glue)

test_string <- "i go to school"

str_split(test_string, " ") %>% 
  map(~str_split(test_string, .x, simplify = T)) %>% 
  flatten() %>%
  map(str_trim) %>%
  keep(~.x != "") %>% 
  map(~glue("phantom({string})", string = .x))
```

This code snippet can easily be implemented in a function and will return the following output.

```
[[1]]
phantom(i)

[[2]]
phantom(i go)

[[3]]
phantom(i go to)

[[4]]
phantom(go to school)

[[5]]
phantom(to school)

[[6]]
phantom(school)
```

I might have misinterpreted your question -- i am not quite sure if you really want the output to have the same format as in your examplary output.